# Error in .standalone_types_check_dot_call(ffi_standalone_check_number_1.0.7, : object 'ffi_standalone_check_number_1.0.7' not found

Tags: time-series, forecasting, forecast

I am trying to run this code to analyze a time series, but the forescat package is giving the following error:

Error in .standalone_types_check_dot_call(ffi_standalone_check_number_1.0.7,  :    object 'ffi_standalone_check_number_1.0.7' not found

Here is my entire code:

```
`suppressMessages(library(readxl))`
`suppressMessages(library(foreign))`
`suppressMessages(library(dynlm))`
`suppressMessages(library(car))`
`suppressMessages(library(lmtest))`
`suppressMessages(library(sandwich))`
`suppressMessages(library(fpp2))`
`suppressMessages(library(tseries))`
`suppressMessages(library(zoo))`
`suppressMessages(library(forecast))`
`suppressMessages(library(ggplot2))`

`varejoms <- structure(c(35.2, 35.6, 39.2, 40.5, 41.6, 40.4, 40.8, 38.7, 37.3, 
37.6, 35.6, 47.4, 34.2, 32.2, 38, 37.5, 38.8, 35, 38.4, 40.2, 38.2, 39.3, 
36, 46.3, 36.4, 34, 39, 37.8, 38.9, 35.3, 37.2, 38.1, 35.6, 38.3, 35.6, 
45.7, 32.2, 31.6, 35.2, 36.8, 37.5, 34.8, 38.4, 38.1, 37, 39, 37.3, 49, 
35.8, 35.3, 40.2, 41.3, 43.9, 41.6, 45.9, 42.3, 42.2, 44, 41.3, 56.9, 38.5, 
38.5, 45.3, 43.6, 46.2, 44.3, 47.5, 46.5, 46.4, 46, 44.1, 61, 42, 40.2, 
44.6, 44.5, 47.8, 45.3, 46.5, 48.5, 47.7, 50.2, 49.3, 64.5, 47, 46.8, 51, 
50.5, 55, 51.3, 52.8, 55.3, 54.8, 55.6, 55.3, 72.2, 54.5, 52.1, 56.2, 57.2, 
60.8, 56.1, 61.8, 61.6, 59.8, 63.3, 57.7, 77.4, 61.4, 51.9, 57.3, 57.9, 
61.9, 57.3, 61.1, 61.1, 60.6, 65.6, 63.5, 83.1, 64.1, 60.2, 67.8, 67.1, 
72.8, 68.5, 71.1, 69.3, 69.9, 71.1, 67.9, 92.7, 67.5, 64.8, 69.1, 69.4, 
79.6, 70.2, 73.8, 72.5, 71.3, 75.6, 74.7, 100.8, 79.5, 75.7, 82.4, 78, 84.8, 
83.2, 84.8, 88.5, 86.3, 91.7, 92.8, 111.4, 92.8, 83.7, 92.5, 88.3, 93.9, 
88.8, 96, 95.9, 93.2, 98.3, 100.5, 128.8, 97.2, 90.2, 94.3, 94.4, 101.1, 
92, 96.4, 98.2, 97.6, 105.8, 103.1, 129.6, 99.6, 87.8, 97, 94.8, 98.6, 93.4, 
98.4, 96.4, 92.5, 100.6, 97.2, 124.5, 91.5, 85.1, 91.6, 88.5, 92.2, 87.4, 
90.5, 88.1, 85.2, 89.4, 93.4, 116.9, 90.8, 84, 89.7, 86.3, 90, 87.3, 90.8, 
93.5, 93.7, 91.4, 93.5, 114.1, 87.8, 81.1, 94.5, 83.2, 89.9, 88.8, 89.3, 
93.7, 93.5, 96.3, 101.3, 118.3, 93.8, 85.2, 90, 86.6, 90, 85.2, 90.9), .Tsp = c(2000, 
2019.5, 12), class = "ts")`
`dvarejo <- diff(varejoms)`

`summary(varejoms)`
`plot(varejoms)`
`library(dygraphs)`
`library(forecast)`
`dygraph(varejoms, main = "Índice de volume de vendas no varejo total de Mato Grosso do Sul <br> (Mensal)  (2011=100) BCB 1479") %>% 
dyAxis("x", drawGrid = TRUE) %>% dyEvent("2005-1-01", "2005", labelLoc = "bottom") %>% 
dyEvent("2015-1-01", "2015", labelLoc = "bottom") %>% dyEvent("2018-1-01", "2018", labelLoc = "bottom") %>% dyEvent("2019-1-01", "2019", labelLoc = "bottom") %>% 
dyOptions(drawPoints = TRUE, pointSize = 2)`
`varejo <- varejoms`
`varejo %>% ggtsdisplay(main = "")`
```

> Error in .standalone_types_check_dot_call(ffi_standalone_check_number_1.0.7,  :
> object 'ffi_standalone_check_number_1.0.7' not found

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, you just need to update the `rlang` package to the most current version (1.1.0).